# Build failed on Hybris server

Tags: node.js, ant, build, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm working with Hybris 6.3 on Windows 10 64 bits.

Recently I tried to run an ant clean all on a hybris system with a module and an add-on, but what once used to run with no problem, not it fails when I try to compile.

The error is not clear, I'm attaching the log output when I run the ant clean all command in [this link](https://pastebin.com/uEa1D8K7), still I'm adding here the last lines of the log in hopes something pops out:

```
     [touch] Creating C:\Helvex\HYBRISCOMM6300P_8-70002554\hybris\temp\hybris\touch\smarteditwebservices_testsrctouch
      [echo] building extension 'personalizationsmartedit'...
      [echo] START of calling grunt packageSkipTests on C:\Helvex\HYBRISCOMM6300P_8-70002554\hybris\bin\ext-content\personalizationsmartedit
      [echo] failonerror=NOT SET, default=true, value=true
      [echo] Creating a link to C:\Helvex\HYBRISCOMM6300P_8-70002554\hybris\bin\ext-content\npmancillary\resources\npm\node_modules in C:\Helvex\HYBRISCOMM6300P_8-70002554\hybris\bin\ext-content\personalizationsmartedit\node_modules
      [exec] Unión creada para C:\Helvex\HYBRISCOMM6300P_8-70002554\hybris\bin\ext-content\personalizationsmartedit\node_modules <<===>> C:\Helvex\HYBRISCOMM6300P_8-70002554\hybris\bin\ext-content\npmancillary\resources\npm\node_modules
      [echo] Running grunt packageSkipTests
      [exec] (node:12228) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
      [exec] [4mRunning "jshint:all" (jshint) task[24m
      [exec] [33mWarning: Path must be a string. Received null Use --force to continue.[39m
      [exec]
      [exec] [31mAborted due to warnings.[39m
      [exec] (node:12228) DeprecationWarning: process.EventEmitter is deprecated. Use require('events') instead.

 BUILD FAILED
 C:\Helvex\HYBRISCOMM6300P_8-70002554\hybris\bin\platform\build.xml:20: The following error occurred while executing this line:
 C:\Helvex\HYBRISCOMM6300P_8-70002554\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.xml:90: The following error occurred while executing this line:
 C:\Helvex\HYBRISCOMM6300P_8-70002554\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.xml:148: The following error occurred while executing this line:
 C:\Helvex\HYBRISCOMM6300P_8-70002554\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\util.xml:20: The following error occurred while executing this line:
 C:\Helvex\HYBRISCOMM6300P_8-70002554\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.xml:155: The following error occurred while executing this line:
 C:\Helvex\HYBRISCOMM6300P_8-70002554\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\compiling.xml:297: The following error occurred while executing this line:
 C:\Helvex\HYBRISCOMM6300P_8-70002554\hybris\bin\platform\resources\ant\util.xml:144: The following error occurred while executing this line:
 C:\Helvex\HYBRISCOMM6300P_8-70002554\hybris\bin\ext-content\personalizationsmartedit\buildcallbacks.xml:65: The following error occurred while executing this line:
 C:\Helvex\HYBRISCOMM6300P_8-70002554\hybris\bin\ext-content\npmancillary\buildcallbacks.xml:276: exec returned: 3
```

It's not really clear to me the reason for which the build is failing, I notice the message Aborted due to warnings but I don't understand the reason behind. The last line says the exec returned: 3 but I have no idea what that means.

The only stuff I've changed lately on my computer was updating Node.js for some web development on other platforms, but I don't know if that affects Hybris.

Hope someone can identify my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that it might be related to the update of the Node.js since I saw in the logs that "grunt" was mentioned. According to https://gruntjs.com/getting-started grunt is installed and managed via npm(the Node.js package manager. ).

I also saw in logs the following: **"DeprecationWarning: process.EventEmitter is deprecated. Use require('events') instead."** This seems to be a Node.js issue which can be seen here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/websocket.io/issues/55

If I were you I would try to downgrade Node.js and see if the issue reproduces.

Comment: I downgraded to 4.4.1 which my coworker has and it ran, thanks.